# What does getRootView() do?

Tags: android

I came across this TextView class method() in some code for taking a screenshot. What does it do, what's its purpose?

```
textView.getRootView()
```

Actually, what is a root view?

Comment: it does exactly what documentation says. Have you checked it?

Answer (score 0):

It is a method of the base class View

It basically lets you find the topmost view in the current view hierarchy.

e.g

```
<LinearLayout>
  <TextView/>
  <RelativeLayout>
     <...something...>
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the above example, the root view would be the top most declared view ie the linear layout

Answer (score 0):

First, [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getRootView()) for `getRootView()`.

[image]

Then the next question is, what is a View Hierarchy?  Read that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004148/android-what-is-view-hierarchy).

So to be succinct, a root view is the top-most view in your current View Hierarchy that is connected to your object you are calling `getRootView()` from.

[image]

Looking at the above tree map, or a binary tree, it would be the root, or top-most node.